# Adobe® LiveCycle® ES - Whats the use of it and Alernatives of it?

Tags: apache-flex

I am pretty much new in this.

I know Remoting, HTTPService and WebService. 
I know on Messaging too.

I just want to know what's the use of LiveCycle DataServices and its Alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a comparison between LiveCycle DataServces ES2 and Blaze:
http://192.150.8.60/products/livecycle/dataservices/compare.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, so alternative of BlazeDS we come up with Adobe Life Cycle Data Services.